# aria=* attributes do not match their roles in slick slider

Tags: html, accessibility, slick.js, wai-aria, audit

Google audit gives accessibility errors in slick sliders code

Assistive technologies, like screen readers, can't interpret ARIA attributes with invalid values

```
<div class="slider-videos slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="listitem" aria-labelledby="slick-slide40" style="width: 412px;">

<li class="slick-active" aria-hidden="false" aria-controls="navigation20" id="slick-slide20" aria-selected="true"><button type="button"data-role="none" tabindex="0">1</button></li>
```

How can I fix it? I have no info of these aria and roles

Comment: First, having an li inside a div rather than a ul is not valid HTML markup. Do you have more code than this you could add?

Comment: Check out the following links for aria roles (https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/roles), states, and properties (https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, at the moment there is not a possibility to change it manually - you can see this [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1544).

I improved the accessibility adding this line of code of my Slip Carousel:

```
accessibility: false
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with `<input type="number">`, which was a combobox - list of possible values appeared below the input and while user types in the input - the options get filtered.

I guess the problem is that the type is `number` but the values are strings ... or simply number type inputs are incompatible with such comboboxes.

I solved this by changing it to `type="text"` and added pattern + inputmode - so that on mobile devices the user still sees the numeric keyboard:

`<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">`

And the error no longer appeared.